How to solve C4244 (conversion possible loss of data) for strong typedef in template
the example: https://godbolt.org/z/bvGjT77vG
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, MyInt)

template<typename T_Int>
T_Int myFunc(long long v) {
    return (T_Int)v;
}

myFunc<MyInt>(1); // <= C4244 here
myFunc<int>(1);

seems only happens on msvc, not even for g++ -Wall
of course, you can perform something like (T_Int)(int)v, but what's the best practice inside the template?

one possible solution:
template<typename T>
class Orig {
public:
    typedef T Type;
};
template<>
class Orig<MyInt> {
public:
    typedef int Type;
};

// and then:
template<typename T_Int>
T_Int myFunc(long long v) {
    return (typename Orig<T_Int>::Type)v;
}


another possible solution:
class MyInt {
public:
    MyInt();
    MyInt(const MyInt &);
    MyInt(const int &);

    // magic here
    template<typename T>
    explicit MyInt(const T &v) : v((int)v) {}
private:
    int v;
};


You're converting from a long long to an int ...  In MSVC, that's a 64-bit to 32-bit conversion. It's warning that you MIGHT lose data, if the value of v is above max_int

@ChrisMM I know that, but inside the template, you are unable to simply perform a proper cast (T_Int)(int)v without extra works

(T_Int)(int)v is NOT a proper cast... don't use "C" style casts in "C++" code.

Just don't use templates for myFunc, but provide (overloaded) implementations that have the exact required behavior you need when an overflow happens.

it's just a simple example, the actual problem may be very unconspicuous, maybe something like MyInt v = someExpr();, so it's not productive to provide overloaded impl
